# Build error after installing Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client NuGet package

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I have created a brand new Xamarin.Android project in Visual Studio 2017. I immediately build and deploy the solution to the Android Emulator and it all works fine.

I then installed the `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client v4.0.2` Nuget package and when I try to build the solution I now get the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added : Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;`

The Output window contains the following:

`1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TestAzure3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  TestAzure3 -> D:\Visual Studio 2017 Projects\TestAzure3\TestAzure3\bin\Debug\TestAzure3.dll
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager+IOnPageChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager+IOnPageChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager+IOnPageChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.NestedScrollView+IOnScrollChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.NestedScrollView+IOnScrollChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.NestedScrollView.IOnScrollChangeListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.NestedScrollView+IOnScrollChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.SwipeRefreshLayout+IOnRefreshListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.SwipeRefreshLayout+IOnRefreshListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.IOnRefreshListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.SwipeRefreshLayout+IOnRefreshListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager+IOnBackStackChangedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager+IOnBackStackChangedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager.IOnBackStackChangedListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager+IOnBackStackChangedListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader+IOnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader+IOnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader.IOnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader+IOnLoadCanceledListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader+IOnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader+IOnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader.IOnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.Content.Loader+IOnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Media.Session.MediaSessionCompat+IOnActiveChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Media.Session.MediaSessionCompat+IOnActiveChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.Media.Session.MediaSessionCompat.IOnActiveChangeListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.Media.Session.MediaSessionCompat+IOnActiveChangeListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.OS.CancellationSignal+IOnCancelListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.OS.CancellationSignal+IOnCancelListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.OS.CancellationSignal.IOnCancelListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.OS.CancellationSignal+IOnCancelListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+ISubUiVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+ISubUiVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider.ISubUiVisibilityListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+ISubUiVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+IVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+IVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider.IVisibilityListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+IVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IOnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IOnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.IOnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.IOnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat+IOnActionExpandListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat+IOnActionExpandListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat.IOnActionExpandListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat+IOnActionExpandListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout+IDrawerListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout+IDrawerListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout.IDrawerListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout+IDrawerListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.SlidingPaneLayout+IPanelSlideListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.SlidingPaneLayout+IPanelSlideListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2152,3): warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.SlidingPaneLayout.IPanelSlideListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.Widget.SlidingPaneLayout+IPanelSlideListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat;
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat$1;
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat$OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback;
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl;
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityManagerCompat;
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat;
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/AppOpsManagerCompat;
1>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/BundleCompat;
1>

1>  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
1>  java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
1>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:613)
1>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
1>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
1>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
1>      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
1>  Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
1>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:605)
1>      ... 4 more
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2521,3): error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

I have tried entering the following commands in the Package Manager Console but I still get the same problem.

```
Update-Package -reinstall
Update-Package
```

Could anybody help me to fix this please?

Comment: Fixed by install the latest version of `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` nuget package.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Install `Xamain.Android.Support.v4` **before** or **after** `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client`?

Comment: I install `Xamain.Android.Support.v4` after installed `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client`. :)

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Fixed, brilliant thanks. Can you post this as an answer please so I can accept it.

Comment: Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `Xamain.Android.Support.v4` after installed `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` nuget package will fix this issue.

Comment: That has fixed it thank you. The only problem is that I now get the following build warning `NU1608 Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 23.3.0 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 27.0.2.1 was resolved.`